# Webdav Path Length over 256

Tags: windows-10, webdav, winscp

I mounted Webdav in Windows 10 as a Network Drive Z.

The Problem is that the Folder Structure and Path Length is way to deep for my Windows Explorer.

```
https://dms-vser01:9090/ix-webdav/DMS -> Z:\File_Name_150Chars.txt

https://dms-vser01:9090/ix-webdav/DMS/Folder/Angebot_2020_Das_ist_Angebot_F%C3%BCr_Einen_TestZweck/File_Name_150Chars.txt
```

I Mounted it as Z: but in the Folder are some Files with a Long Filename. Exportet Messages from Outlook with the Subject as Filename, i know its stupid but company is working with a special Software that creats those Files.

The Total path is about 280 Chars, in Firefox or WinSCP i am able to view these Files. But Windows Explorer does not show any Files, Folder is empty. But there are still Files with a short Filename.

Also tried any solutions from Windwos with Enable Long Path or Win32 File System.